# BMI calcuration in Python wrong resaults

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I have to create a BMI calculation for people from my list

```
patients = [[70, 1.8], [80, 1.9], [150, 1.7]]
```

and now my function :

```
def calculate_bmi(weight, height):
    return weight / (height ** 2)

for patient in patients:
    weight, height = patients[0]
    bmi = round(weight/ (height * height), 1)
    print("Patient's BMI is: %f" % bmi)
```

she shows me the first person's result [0] three times. I know that I have the first person value in the function.
The second thing is how to reduce the BMI value to one digit after the decimal point, e.g. 21.6

```
Patient's BMI is: 21.600000
Patient's BMI is: 21.600000
Patient's BMI is: 21.600000
```

I have no idea how to save a function to count the BMI for each person on the list.
Anybody can help me ? Thx for answers.

Comment: `weight, height = patient`, not `patients[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a few things in your code. 
When you are iterating over the `patients` list, you need to assign `weight, height = patient[0],patient[1]`

Just check the code below:

```
for patient in patients:
     weight, height = patient[0],patient[1]
     bmi = round(weight/ (height * height), 1)
     print("Patient's BMI is: ", bmi)
```

Also remove the `%f` from your `print` function to display just one digit after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

You are repeatedly setting weight and height to the first element in the patients list by using `weight, height = patients[0]`; keep in mind the for loop is iterating over all patients in the list, so you can just use the patient variable as shown below

```
def calculate_bmi(weight, height):
    return weight / (height ** 2.0)


for patient in patients:
    weight, height = patient
    bmi = round(weight/ (height * height), 1)
    print("Patient's BMI is: %f" % bmi)
```